# gwidgets ggraphics cutting edge of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gwidgets

This may be something really obvious, but I am struggling to find a good resource explaining how to use features of `gwidgets`. With some help I have this script which creates checkboxes which alter a list of file names which are then used to create a plot of the checked files using `ggplot`. The problem is that the plot is getting cut off at the right edge and I have no idea how to fix this.

**EDIT:** I see some of you have been busy down-rating me, but now this should work if you run it with the file I provided. I have a suspicion that the problem arises from `cairoDevice` and the way ggraphics renders the plot.

```
read.table("foo.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", row.names=1)

ggplot(MeanFrameMelt, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=Legend, group=Legend))+ 
  geom_line()+ 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='NA', colour='black', size = 1), 
        legend.position = "none")+ 
  ylab("Tag Density (mean coverage/bp)")+ 
  xlab("Distance from reference side (bp)")+ 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("V1", "V200", "V400"), labels=c("-10000", "0", "10000"))+ 


GraphFiles <- FileNamesOrig
w <- gwindow("Tag Density Checkboxes", width = 1000)
g <- ggroup(container = w, horizontal = FALSE)
add(g, ggraphics())
lyt <- glayout(container = g, horizontal = FALSE)
print(p)
```

[foo.cvs (this is the MeanFrameMelt)](http://sdrv.ms/UW1UlZ)

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
This is what the graph looks like for me. I don't know what is going on, I am exporting the `data.frame` with this command:

```
write.table(MeanFrameMelt, file="test.cvs", sep=",", col.names=TRUE)
```

but then when I run it with the exported file I get exactly what agstudy got. The files are supposed to be identical.

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

Tested it with gput (thank you for the suggestion) and now its creating the correct plot:
[New file](http://sdrv.ms/10pxJpq)

Use `dget(file="test.txt")`

Comment: You should give a reproducible example.

Comment: Please add sample code and library(s) that you are using for this example.

Comment: ok i'll add it later today, i'm on a different computer right now

Comment: ok should be fine now, btw agstudy thanks for your help on my other questions.

Comment: if you use `dput` you can output the `MeanFrameMelt` variable exactly as R sees it in your first session ...

Answer (score 1):

I just reorganized your code, but I can't reproduce the problem. You have to call the plot actions inside a handelr to interact later with user(e.g zoom , mouse events). I show an example here. 
First time you run you have the plot with an ugly axis. Then when you click in a region , the plot is refreshed and you have a nice axis.

```
## I define my plot
p <- ggplot(MeanFrameMelt, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=Legend, group=Legend))+ 
  geom_line()+ 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='NA', colour='black', size = 1), 
        legend.position = "none")+ 
  ylab("Tag Density (mean coverage/bp)")+ 
  xlab("Distance from reference side (bp)")
## init gwidgets
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
w   <- gwindow("Tag Density Checkboxes", width = 1000)
g   <- ggroup(container = w, horizontal = FALSE)
gg  <- ggraphics(container=g)
lyt <- glayout(container = g, horizontal = FALSE)
## I plot it the first time 
print(p)
## I add a handler
ID <- addHandlerChanged(gg, handler=function(h,...) {
   p <-  p + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("V1", "V200", "V400"), 
                     labels=c("-1000", "0", "1000"))
   print(p)
})
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what is going wrong, I made an edit to my question, please have a look. If I run the original `data.frame` I still get the last 0 of the 10000 cut off.

Comment: @crysis405 It is not clear what you have done with you files. You read  the file, you try to plot it doesn't work. then you save the file "export, you reread it and it works?

Comment: No. I'm using RStudio where I have my whole script which generated the MeanFrameMelt `data.frame`. I export this `data.frame` with the `write.table` command I posted above. My original MeanFrameMelt `data.frame` gives me the normal graph I posted above. But the exported table give me the same weird graph you got.

Comment: Please test this with the new file. Thanks

Comment: @crysis405 the x aes of ggplot2 is a factor that 's why you have such plot. you need to read it as numeric or coerce it to numeric for example try this `MeanFrameMelt$variable <-as.numeric(gsub('V','',MeanFrameMelt$variable))`

Comment: the 10000 is still cut of if I use `scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1", "200", "400"), labels=c("-10000", "0", "10000"))`. I need on the x-axis the median to be 0 and the min: -10000 while the max: 10000.